# xarray mask outside list of coordinates

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray

I have an Xarray DataArray with values over rectangular 2D grid, and a list of points (pairs of coordinate values) from an arbitrary subset of that grid contained in a pandas Dataframe.

How do I mask out values (i.e. set equal to NaN) in the DataArray whose grid coordinates do not appear in the list points?

e.g. consider the DataArray

```py
In [35]: da = xr.DataArray(data=np.random.randint(10, size=(5, 6)), coords={"x": np.linspace(0, 10, 5), "y": np.linspace(0, 12, 6)})

In [36]: da
Out[36]: 
<xarray.DataArray (x: 5, y: 6)>
array([[6, 0, 2, 3, 9, 8],
       [7, 6, 4, 8, 5, 8],
       [7, 4, 4, 5, 4, 7],
       [9, 8, 8, 1, 8, 0],
       [8, 9, 4, 3, 3, 6]])
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) float64 0.0 2.5 5.0 7.5 10.0
  * y        (y) float64 0.0 2.4 4.8 7.2 9.6 12.0
```

and dataframe

```py
In [44]: coords = pd.DataFrame([[2.5, 4.8], [2.5, 7.2], [5.0, 12.0], [7.5, 7.2], [10.0, 2.4]], columns=["x_coord", "y_coord"])

In [45]: coords
Out[45]: 
   x_coord   y_coord
0      2.5       4.8
1      2.5       7.2
2      5.0      12.0
3      7.5       7.2
4     10.0       2.4
```

then I expect the output to be:

```py
Out[84]: 
<xarray.DataArray (x: 5, y: 6)>
array([[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan,  4.,  8., nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,  7.],
       [nan, nan, nan,  1., nan, nan],
       [ 8., nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]])
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) float64 0.0 2.5 5.0 7.5 10.0
  * y        (y) float64 0.0 2.4 4.8 7.2 9.6 12.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the dataframe to an xarray object by setting the x and y coordinates as the index, then using `to_xarray`. since you don't have any data left, I'll just assign a "flag" variable:

```py
In [20]: flag = (
    ...:     coords.assign(flag=1)
    ...:     .set_index(["x_coord", "y_coord"])
    ...:     .flag
    ...:     .to_xarray()
    ...:     .fillna(0)
    ...:     .rename({"x_coord": "x", "y_coord": "y"})
    ...: )

In [21]: flag
Out[21]:
<xarray.DataArray 'flag' (x: 4, y: 4)>
array([[0., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0.]])
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) float64 2.5 5.0 7.5 10.0
  * y        (y) float64 2.4 4.8 7.2 12.0
```

To deal with floating point issues, I'll reindex the array to ensure the dims are consistent with the arrays:

```py
In [22]: flag = flag.reindex(x=da.x, y=da.y, method="nearest", tolerance=1e-9, fill_value=0)

In [23]: flag
Out[23]:
<xarray.DataArray 'flag' (x: 5, y: 6)>
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) float64 0.0 2.5 5.0 7.5 10.0
  * y        (y) float64 0.0 2.4 4.8 7.2 9.6 12.0
```

This is now the same shape as your array and can can be used as a mask:

```py
In [24]: da.where(flag)
Out[24]:
<xarray.DataArray (x: 5, y: 6)>
array([[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan,  7.,  0., nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,  5.],
       [nan, nan, nan,  8., nan, nan],
       [nan,  8., nan, nan, nan, nan]])
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) float64 0.0 2.5 5.0 7.5 10.0
  * y        (y) float64 0.0 2.4 4.8 7.2 9.6 12.0
```

Just in case it's useful, if you wanted to do the opposite; that is, extract the values from the DataArray at the points given in your dataframe, you could use xarray's [advanced indexing rules](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/indexing.html#more-advanced-indexing) to pull specific points out of the array using DataArray indexers:

```py
In [28]: da.sel(
    ...:     x=coords.x_coord.to_xarray(),
    ...:     y=coords.y_coord.to_xarray(),
    ...:     method="nearest",
    ...:     tolerance=1e-9, # use a (low) tolerance to handle floating-point error
    ...: )

Out[28]:
<xarray.DataArray (index: 5)>
array([7, 0, 5, 8, 8])
Coordinates:
    x        (index) float64 2.5 2.5 5.0 7.5 10.0
    y        (index) float64 4.8 7.2 12.0 7.2 2.4
  * index    (index) int64 0 1 2 3 4
```